# Obtain a specific data from my model - Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to understand how to obtain some data from my models.

I have a model like this,

```
class Device(models.Model):
    dev_id= models.CharField(max_length=16, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    dev_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)

    fleet_id = models.ForeignKey(Fleet, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.dev_eui
```

If for example one of my devices has the `dev_id` like "lop7576", I want to obtain two data, its `dev_name` and its `fleet_id`.

If I do the following I obtain all the info from this device,

```
jq1 = Device.objects.filter(dev_id="lop7576")
```

But how can I obtain only this two values in string/int format directly?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.values()` function like this:

```
jq1 = Device.objects.filter(dev_id="lop7576").values('dev_name', 'fleet_id')
```